# NVDA not reading v-html tags

Tags: html, jsp, screen-readers, nvda

NVDA Screen reader is reading following:

```
<span class="sr-only"><spring:theme code="checkout.doctor.name" /> {{ doctor.firstName.toLowerCase() }} {{ doctor.lastName.toLowerCase() }}</span>
```

But not reading the following with v-html content in it:

```
<span class="sr-only" v-html="phoneNumber(doctor.doctorContactsDetails)">{{ doctor.firstName.toLowerCase() }} {{ doctor.lastName.toLowerCase() }}</span>
```

Tried adding spring theme in it, still no luck:

```
<span class="sr-only" v-html="formatAddress(doctor.doctorAddress)"><spring:theme code="checkout.doctor.address" /></span>
```

Comment: Seems like more of a vue.js question.  If you add that tag to your question, you might get more responses.  I don't know vue.js but I do know screen readers and nvda.  If you can post what the html resolves to, then I can probably help.  It would also help if you show what nvda says in the example that works and what it says in the example that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the spring:theme content before the data that you want your screen reader to read:
Here is the order: (span class for sr-only) spring:theme (data to read)

```
((span class="sr-only" ) (spring:theme code="checkout.doctor.address" ) (span v-html="formatAddress(doctor.doctorAddress)"))
```

Close span tags accordingly